# Configuration files for javascript so base url can be changed

Tags: javascript, ajax

We are using AJAX to call WCF services from various sub folders.
So the urls of the DOM OBJECT window.location.HREF
would be :

```
http://localhost:80/myVirtualDirectory/Reporting/reporting.aspx
```

OR

```
http://localhost:80/myVirtualDirectory/Sales/sales.aspx
```

My service actually resides at:

```
http://localhost:80/myVirtualDirectory/
```

When I am calling from a "sub folder" the service cannot be found or I have to put *.svc files in parent and all sub folders.
So need all my AJAX "url" to start with

```
http://localhost:80/myVirtualDirectory/
```

Only I don't know what myVirtualDirectory is going to be as we deploy this application to our customers' web sites.
I wrote a scriptblock to push this out as:

```
var urlBase = "http://localhost:80/myVirtualDirectory/"
```

The code in C# was like this (abridged)

```
"var urlBase = '//'+window.location.host+" + Request.ApplicationName + " '/' ";
```

Is there a better way? 
Please keep in mind that we are moving away from ASPX in favour of plain old html pages(POHP) with knockout.js

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag on your HTML:

```
<head>
  <base href="http://localhost:80/myVirtualDirectory/">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use servletContext.getContextPath():
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath()

Comment: Use the result from getContextPath to build your html <base> tag